# This is the last time I see you OR I see you, this is the last time?

Tags: sentence-construction

Usually, we are using "this is the last time I see you", but can I write it in this way which is **I see you, this is the last time**?

Is it fine to turn the sentence in that way?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence sounds peculiar to me, I wouldn't expect to hear it in normal speech.

The first sentence itself sounds quite.. forced? It's correct, but I would use it in that short form if I was perhaps annoyed with somebody, or making it very clear that it's the absolute last time, especially with emphasis on the word "last."

Perhaps instead you might choose one of these:

> This is the last time **I'll** see you [for a while/because/etc...]

> This is the last time I **can** see you.